# Is there a separate word for the time domain when working with digital signals?

Tags: digital, analog

Typically the phrase "time domain" implies an analog signal *x(t)*, but I've also seen it referring to a digital signal *x[n]*.  Is there any phrase that refers to *x[n]*, but not *x(t)*?

Comment: discrete-time domain signals, $x[n],X[k]$ etc., are referred to as **sequences**...

Comment: If you want to be accurate: "digital" refers to a signal whose amplitudes are restricted to a finite set. "Digital" is not related to the properties of the signal's time domain.

Comment: You are correct, in this case I'm referring to discrete digital signals vs. continuous analog signals.

Answer (score 2):

I use sampled-time domain or discrete-time domain.  I *think* I've heard other people use other terms, so they can chime in (discretely).

Comment: I use "discrete-time domain" and "discrete-time signals".

Comment: Can I chime in continuously? Curious minds want to know. ;-)

Comment: He types in, digitally.